# Degree of elements in exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

How one determines the degree of an element in the exterior algebra $\bigwedge V$, for a graded vector space V.

e.g.Is it true that $\wedge^n V^2=0$, as elements of $V^2$ are of degree 2?

In particular, when does the exterior product vanish?
Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the notation, what does $V^2$ mean?

Comment: as $V$ is graded $V=V^0\oplus V^1\oplus V^2\oplus..$